# Python3: condition with an element of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I know that it is so stupid question but I'm stuck. How should I write this condition:

```
some_dic = { "single": single_player,
             "s": single_player,
             ...
             "m": multiplayer
           }

mode_choice = ' '
while mode_choice not in some_dic:
    mode_choice = input("Enter The Game Mode: ")

if some_dic(mode_choice) == single_player
   ...
```

I mean before the last line, of course. While executing a popup: "'dict' object is not callable" appears. I'm asking for a solution and a some explanation, if it is not a problem.

Best regards

Comment: you should try with some_dict[mode_choice] instead of ( )

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I told that it is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing elements from a dictionary should be done with square brackets:

```
some_dic[made_choice]
```

Nevertheless, there's a better pattern you can use to avoid checking the dictionary twice (you are doing it at `mode_choice not in some_dic` and `some_dic[mode_choice]` for the same text):

```
player = None
while player is None:
    player = some_dict.get(input("Enter The Game Mode: "))
```

Like this, `player` will be either `None` or one valid output from your dictionary (eg.: `single_player`) and the loop will persist while it is None.